# Windows Server - Validation Script w/wo GUI

Tags: validation, server

I am looking for advice on the correct scripting language for what I am trying to accomplish. Our organization has several (50+) Microsoft Servers that require semi-manual validation after reboots from patching. I want to create a script that can do the following;

- Ping remote servers for offline/online status.
- Check remote server services to validate 'Running' status.
- Perform action to fix server service issues, such as force kill, then start and validate.
- Provide feedback in a GUI or even on the terminal level.
- Post results to a text file or web document.

We are trying to find the best scripting language to accomplish this task. Once I know the best direction, I can start the research on how to code the specific requirements.

Comment: As you selected already the PowerShell tag, I would suggest you proceed with this language.

Comment: these are a lot of questions in one. To check a server you can use the PING command - to check a certain port - you'll need different approach. To execute checks on a remote machine you can use PSEXEC or WMIC command. The easiest way to create UI on windows is with HTA (also can output to the terminal). What should 'post on web document' mean? There are command line http clients which you can use in case you have dedicated web service..

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use case for [PowerShell OVF](https://github.com/PowerShell/Operation-Validation-Framework)

Answer (score 1):

If you use PowerShell:

- Ping remote servers for offline/online status:

You can use `Test-NetConnection`.

- Check remote server services to validate 'Running' status.

You can create a PSSession (`New-PSSession`) and then request the service status.

- Perform action to fix server service issues, such as force kill, then start and validate.

With the PSSession, you can executes commands on the remote server as you wish.

Regarding the last two points, you can of course return output back to your console and also log any events. 
However, I suggest you clarify your question, so one can provide a more specific answer.